# Black Box, AI and inhumanity

Tags: nier-automata, nier

About the black box (spoilers!)

> Why is it stated that installing standard AI (instead of black box) is considered inhumane? After all standard AI is also artificial, and may be even less conscious than the black box?
>
>  Is this related to setting from other games in the series?
>
>  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Earlier in the game it is revealed that humans were extinct before the alien invasion.  So it would have been other androids building the YoRHa units.

Presumably those androids believed that their consciousness was superior (or at least distinct) from machine consciousness, so it would be more humane to use (enslave?) machine consciousness when making the soldiers.

As you play the game, you might get the idea that the differences are far smaller than those androids assumed.